# shp2pgsql gsid conversion issues

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm fairly new to PostGIS. I've imported a shp file countless times in different ways. Here's my latest attempt.

`shp2pgsql -d -s 4269 /var/www/Shape/Hamilton_City/Election_Poll_Boundaries.shp city_hamilton | psql -U postgres -d shape`

I'm importing to srid 4269 because the .prj file says:
`GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]`

When I do any type of search on the geometry of the polygons as in:
`select  ST_Astext(geom) AS coordinates FROM city_hamilton limit 1;`
I get odd coordinates like:

**MULTIPOLYGON(((574380.4001 4808575.0399,574434.7803 4808545.44,574496.2521 4808512.3351,**.....

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it's probably in UTM (or else) with units in meters, not in degrees. Try opening the shapefile in QGIS/Arcmap and look at the projection properties to find out the proper EPSG code.

Comment: Thanks, I had looked it up in GGIS and it recognizes it as EPSG:4269 - NAD83. When I look at the KML version of the same data from the source the output is actual coordinates.

Also, in researching the difference between 4269 and 4326 I can see that thet are comparatively similar geometry. So the numbers wouldn't be so far off (especially in the 10's of thousands [ie. -79.8874647968378,43.289415004346  vs  574380.4001 4808575.0399 ).